# Unable to execute oracle procedure in PLSQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am having sample Procedure as Below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_Table1
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Sample UserName' AS UserName    
    FROM Dual;
END;
```

Now I want to run this Proc in PLSQL developer.I tried the below but its generating error

```
begin
  proc_Table1;
end;
```

Its Displaying

[image]

Thanks for the Help.

Any Idea why this Happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you created the procedure, you should have been alerted to the fact that you had syntax errors.  If you're going to run a `SELECT` statement, you need to do something with the results-- either populate a local variable or open a cursor or something else.  The code you've posted is also missing the `IS/AS` keyword

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_Table1
AS
  l_username VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Sample UserName' AS UserName    
    INTO l_username
    FROM Dual;
END;
```

will be syntactically valid.  It doesn't appear, however, to be particularly useful-- you procedure isn't modifying the database and has no way to communicate with the caller so it isn't doing anything meaningful.  As a general principal, you would also generally want to use a simple PL/SQL assignment operator to populate a local variable rather than selecting from `dual`, i.e.

```
l_username := 'Sample UserName';
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply How to execute Above Statement

Comment: @JavaBeginner - The procedure call you posted in your question will work with the procedure I posted.  As I said, it won't actually do anything since the procedure doesn't modify anything and has no way to communicate with the caller so you won't see anything happen when you call the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_Table1(UserName OUT VARCHAR2)
    AS
    BEGIN
      SELECT 'Sample UserName' INTO UserName    
        FROM Dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(UserName);
    END PROC_TABLE1;
    -------------------------------
    How to Execute
    -------------------------------
    declare
    name varchar2(50);
    result varchar2(100);
    begin
    proc_table1(name);
    end;
```